# How to Edit XML file in Java ME?

Tags: xml, file, java-me

I know how to read or parse .xml file. I need to know how to edit this .xml file and save it on same location ( phone memory/sd card ) ?

Comment: you want to edit after the parsing or without parsing ?

Comment: after parsing is good, i guess. if u could answer both, it will be good. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can give a clue/logic for it.

Suppose you have your xml file as

```
<XML>
     <NAME>ABC</NAME>
     <JOB>DEV</JOB>
     ...
</XML>
```

Now you need to read this xml and edit after reading for e.g. like this will be resultan xml file.

```
<XML>
     <NAME>XYZ</NAME>
     <JOB>DEVELOPER</JOB>
     ...
</XML>
```

so for this purpose, you need to open two File Connection at same time like below,

```
FileConnection fc1 = (FileConnection) Connector.open("<File URL>");
FileConnection fc2 = (FileConnection) Connector.open("<File URL>");
```

for fc2 your filename will be changed.

Now start reading characters from the first file and write them in second file ( simple C language logic ). you can make changes wherever you want, like when you parse and get ABC, replace it with XYZ same other strings.

Comment: if you think it logically, you can implement it very easily , take an example of copying note-book from your friend's note-book. first you read a part/line and then you write it in your note-book, simple.

Answer (score 1):

@Lucifer Taking out your idea, i've developed something tht can edit existing .XML. **Thankz**.

```
OutputStream os = fc.openDataOutputStream();
                        os.write(ReadChangedXml(result).getBytes());
                        os.close();
```

**Your object should contain old value**

```
 public synchronized String ReadNChangeXml(<your object>) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer key = new StringBuffer();
    byte c;

    try {
         in = fc.openInputStream();
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
        do_alert("Open failed for Change Xml.", 1000);
        }

    try {
        boolean scan = false;
        while (((c = (byte) in.read()) != -1)) {

            if (c == '>' ) {
                scan = true;
                buf.append((char) c);
                continue;
            }

            if (scan == true && c != '<') {
                key.append((char) c);
            }

            if (scan == true && c == '<') 
               {
                 scan = false;
                  if (key.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(<your object variable>))
                        buf.append(<new value>);
                  else
                     buf.append(key.toString());
               }
                buf.append((char) c);
                key = new StringBuffer();
                continue;
            }
            if (scan == false) {
                buf.append((char) c);
            }
      }

    } catch (Exception E) {
        do_alert("Read failed for Change Xml.", 1000);
    }

   return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: my code hav some extra things, just pasted the stuff to get a basic idea. :)